# Kubernetes: Not able to communicate within two services (different pod, same namespace)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns

I am not able to communicate between two services.

post-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python-data-deployment
  labels:
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: python-web-selector
    tier: backend
  template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: python-web-selector
       tier: backend
   spec:
    containers:
    - name: python-web-pod
      image: sakshiarora2012/python-backend:v10
      ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
```

post-deployment2.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python-data-deployment2
  labels:
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: python-web-selector2
    tier: backend
  template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: python-web-selector2
       tier: backend
   spec:
    containers:
    - name: python-web-pod2
      image: sakshiarora2012/python-backend:v8
      ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
```

post-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-data-service
spec:
  selector:
   app: python-web-selector
   tier: backend
  ports:
      - port: 5000
        nodePort: 30400
  type: NodePort
```

post-service2.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-data-service2
spec:
  selector:
   app: python-web-selector2
   tier: backend
  ports:
      - port: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

When I go and try to ping from 1 container to another, it is not able to ping

```
root@python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj:/project# ping python-data-service.default.svc.cluster.local
PING python-data-service.default.svc.cluster.local (10.107.11.236) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- python-data-service.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 139ms
```

If I see dns entry it is showing

```
sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup  python-data-service 
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   python-data-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.107.11.236

sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % 
sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup  python-data-service2
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   python-data-service2.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.103.97.40


sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % kubectl get pod -o wide 
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dnsutils                                   1/1     Running   0          5m54s   172.17.0.9   minikube   <none>           <none>
python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj    1/1     Running   0          47m     172.17.0.6   minikube   <none>           <none>
python-data-deployment2-764744b97d-mc9gm   1/1     Running   0          43m     172.17.0.8   minikube   <none>           <none>
python-db-deployment-d54f6b657-rfs2b       1/1     Running   0          44h     172.17.0.7   minikube   <none>           <none>

sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % kubectl describe svc python-data-service
Name:                     python-data-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"python-data-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"no...
Selector:                 app=python-web-selector,tier=backend
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.107.11.236
Port:                     <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30400/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.6:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration % kubectl describe svc python-data-service2
Name:              python-data-service2
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"python-data-service2","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"p...
Selector:          app=python-web-selector2,tier=backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.103.97.40
Port:              <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.8:5000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

sakshiarora@Sakshis-MacBook-Pro Student_Registration %

I think if in DNS table it show if of range 172,17.0.X then it will work, but not sure why it is not showing in dns entry, Any pointers?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for `python-data-service` service to be `NodePort` type? You want to access it from outside cluster ? If not then `ClusterIP` should be okay

Comment: Yes, I want to access it from outside

Comment: hey @SakshiAhuja what is the response if you use DNS instead of IP? is it a timeout or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Ping doesn't work on services `ClusterIP` addresses because they are from virtual addresses created by iptables rules that redirect packets to the endpoints(pods).

You should be able to ping a pod, but not a service.

You can use `curl` or `wget`

For example `wget -qO- POD_IP:80`

or You can try

```
wget -qO- http://your-service-name:port/yourpath
curl POD_IP:port_number
```

Comment: Ping was to mention the communication, I cant even make a rest call from 1 service to another root@python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj:/project# curl http://python-data-service:5000/getdata
^C
root@python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj:/project# curl http://172.17.0.8:5000/getdata
[{"student_name": "aaa", "student_id": "id", "student_email": "email", "student_phone": "phone", "student_class": "class"}]

Comment: @SakshiAhuja ping doesn't support for services

Comment: Did the curl too, its working if I provide ip address but not working if I provide service name. Posted in above comments

Comment: @SakshiAhuja try this ```wget -q -O- http://your-service-name``` even in the answer I have updated this. and this shuld work I have tried and working on my cluster.

Comment: Tried, no luck root@python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj:/project# wget -q -O- http://python-data-service:5000/getdata
^C
root@python-data-deployment-7bd65dc685-htxmj:/project# wget -q -O- http://172.17.0.8:5000/getdata
[{"student_name": "aaa", "student_id": "id", "student_email": "email", "student_phone": "phone", "student_class": "class"}]

Comment: @SakshiAhuja I would suggest then expose services as ClsuterIP and then try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218136/discussion-between-dashrath-mundkar-and-sakshi-ahuja).

Comment: did you already try the fully qualified service name?
wget -q -O- python-data-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/getdata

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `python-data-service` from outside the cluster using `NodePort` and you are using minikube you should be able to do so by using `curl $(minikube service python-data-service --url)` from anywhere outside the cluster i.e from your system

If you want to communicate between two microservice within the cluster then simply use `ClusterIP` type service instead of `NodePort` type.

To identity if it's a service issue or pod issue use PODIP directly in the `curl` command. From the output of `kubectl describe svc python-data-service` the Pod IP for service `python-data-service` is  `172.17.0.6`. So try `curl 172.17.0.6:5000/getdata`

Comment: So you are suggesting if I use cluster ip on both service, it will be able to communicate?

Comment: If you don't want to access from outside the cluster then there is no need to use `NodePort`

Comment: The curl command works for other service which is `ClusterIP` type?

Comment: I am having just two services, I tried putting ClusterIP, still not working

Comment: It seems the corresponding pod IP for service `python-data-service` is 172.17.0.6. So you should try `curl 172.17.0.6:5000/getdata` to verify if it's working using PODIP

Answer (score 1):

In order to start debugging your services I would suggest the following steps:

Check that your service 1 is accessible as a Pod:

`kubectl run test1 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - http://172.17.0.6:5000`

Check that your service 2 is accessible as a Pod:

`kubectl run test2 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - 172.17.0.8:5000`

Then, check that your service 1 is accessible as a Service using the corresponding cluster IP and then DNS Name:

`kubectl run test2 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - 10.107.11.236:5000`

`kubectl run test2 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - http://python-data-service:5000`

Then, check that your service 2 is accessible as a Service using the corresponding cluster IP and then DNS Name:

`kubectl run test2 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - 10.103.97.40:5000`

`kubectl run test2 -it --rm=true --image=busybox --restart=Never -n default -- wget -O - http://python-data-service2:5000`

Then, if needed, check that your service 2 is accessible through your node port (you would need to know the IP Address of the Node where the service has been exposed, for instance in minikube it should work:)

```
wget -O - http://192.168.99.101:30400
```

From your Service manifest I can recommend as a good practice to specify both `port` and `targetPort` as you can see at

https://canterafonseca.eu/kubernetes/certification/application/developer/cncf/k8s/cloud/native/computing/ckad/deployments/services/preparation-k8s-ckad-exam-part4-services.html#-services

On the other hand if you only need to expose to the outside world one of the services you can create a headless service (see also my blog post above).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect to your pods maybe try port-forward to see if you can connect & then check the connectivity in two pods.
Last check if there is default deny network policy set there - maybe you have some restrictions at network level.

```
kubectl get networkpolicy -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the logs using `kubectl logs PODNAME` so that you know what's happening. From first sight,  I think you need to expose the ports of both services: `kubectl port-forward yourService PORT:PORT`.